# Necromancer kill and Item acquisiton

Tags: werewolv.es

Does the Necromancer's kill-revive-swap ability grant them the Items of the person they killed, like with other killing abilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not.

Since the Necromancer's kill is a little bit different to how normal kills work (the kill is invisible) it doesn't go through the same logic as the majority of kills in the game and does not trigger the item pillage.